# How do I check bad sector on my android with ADB recovery mode?

Tags: adb

I am finally able to install CWM on my asus. I suspected the asus didn't do well and there could be too many bad blocks on it's NAND.

So Now that I can do fast boot and recovery and adb, I think I would scan the whole NAND memory and see if something is bad and then mark it.

You know, like chkdsk or fdisk

How would I do so?

Comment: Have you tried `fsck` in ADB while in recovery mode? It might not work, but then it might.

Comment: Also, the whole of the NAND is not available to ADB even in recovery. The modem and bootloader partitions are protected, for example. Fastboot doesn't have anything like `fsck`, and it is the only mode in which these protected partitions are accessible.

Comment: Maybe try using the block device id of the NAND from `fdisk` for `fsck`?

Answer (score 4):

You can follow these steps to check your Android NAND chip partition which checks bad blocks:

1.for your data safety,backup your data to pc or cloud first.

2.boot to recovery.

3.unmount all partition in recovery.

4.connect your phone to pc.

5.execute `adb shell` .

6.use `cd` command go to your partition directory,usual in:

```
/dev/block/platform/soc.0/<chip ID>/by-name
```

or like:

```
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name
```

for example:

```
cd /dev/block/platform/soc.0/12345678.sdhci/by-name
```

after enter directory,you can execute `ls` command show all partition name,like system,cache,userdata,etc.

7.execute `e2fsck` command with `-cfv` parameter and partition name,for example,you want check userdata ( /data ) partition with check bad blocks:

```
e2fsck -cfv userdata
```

or system partition:

```
e2fsck -cfv system
```

Additional Information:

The `-c` parameter for `e2fsck` is check for bad blocks and add them to the badblock list, you can execute `e2fsck -h` get more information.

Comment: `-c` doesn't work on android, `badblocks not found`