# Corrupt files in microSD - How to know if files are damaged?

Tags: external-sd, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 with a 4GB Kingston microSD.

This microSD has only a few files *(that I can remember) - visible both in PC and in file manager (default app) in the smartphone*:

- Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5.iso *(1.6 GB - for PPSSPP Emulator)*.
- Yu-Gi-Oh! Tag Force 5.cso *(1.5 GB - for PPSSPP Emulator)*.
- Folder "DIR" - 0 files in it.
- Folder "Music" - 73 .mp3 files.
- Yu-Gi-Oh! Forbidden Memories.iso *(495 mb - for ePSXe Emulator)*.

**Background**

In previous ocassions, the PPSSPP emulator didn't read the .ISO file *(and I though it was the .ISO file)*, so, I compress the .ISO file in a .CSO file *which I read in formus that is recongized by the PPSSPP emulator*, however, the .CSO file was also not recognized and the app freezes.

Trying discarging both files, I used the emulator in my PC and all works well, so, I decided to move all my Music "73 .mp3 files" to the "microSD". After the music files where there, I use the default music player, but most of the files *(when trying to play "random")* says: **not supported** and skips until it finds a .mp3 file "apparentely" not corrupted or ends playing abruptly.

Even some .mp3 files plays for a few minutes, ends abruptly and search other random .mp3 file.

**What have I tried?**

- Scan for viruses the microSD.
- Download from other sites the ISO files.
- Format the microSD "via the available option in the Samsung Galaxy and vía PC (right click > Format device)".
- Following this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/645791/702051) I downloaded (SD Card Formatter 5.0.1), but the formatting process failed for both format options *(quick and overwrite)*.

For me, it this weird how this microSD can corrupt files *(most of them)* and not others. Also, my goal is use the microSD for storage games that I can use with the PPSSPP emulator "mostly, Yu-Gi-Oh! games".

I'll replace my microSD, but, before to do that, I want to know:

- Is there a way to activate a log file in Android for check wheter are files corrupted or missing?
- What resources or what else can I do for save the 4GB microSD for use as I intend to do?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can try:

Use fsck to check and repair bad blocks [How do I check bad sector on my android with ADB recovery mode?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137223/how-do-i-check-bad-sector-on-my-android-with-adb-recovery-mode)

(alternatively follow [this guide](https://www.andreafortuna.org/technology/android/check-and-fix-sd-card-from-the-android-terminal-emulator/) for FAT formatted cards)
Obviously, both need root, you could also try to run it from a regular Linux box.

And finally, [how to run scripts on boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/how-can-i-run-a-script-on-boot) and use logcat perhaps to view the results. I would think that Android already does this check automatically, but...